# Randomize div id order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get some divs with an id to randomize the order they appear in. I've found a script that supposedly will do this, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why mine isn't working.

Basically, when the page loads the HTML will read like this:

```
<div class="main">
   <div id="box">1</div>
   <div id="box">2</div>
   <div id="box">3</div>
   <div id="box">4</div>
</div>
```

But the code when applied will randomize the order in which they appear (in the browser), like so:

```
<div class="main">
   <div id="box">3</div>
   <div id="box">1</div>
   <div id="box">4</div>
   <div id="box">2</div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript that supposedly is making it all work:

```
 function reorder() {
           var grp = $(".main").children();
           var cnt = grp.length;

           var temp,x;
           for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
               temp = grp[i];
             x = Math.floor(Math.random() * cnt);
             grp[i] = grp[x];
             grp[x] = temp;
         }
         $(grp).remove();
         $(".main").append($(grp));
       }
```

I thought it was because I had an id property, but even if I strip that out and just make it a plain old div tag, it doesn't work :/

Here is the the like to a js fiddle of the code in question...
[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samfish/TkwWE/1/)

There are a few questions here similar to this, but they're all older topics, so I hope no one minds my making a new one. I'm still pretty new to javascript, if that isn't already obvious :D

Comment: To start with **never** give the same id to two elements.

Comment: It works fine once you include jQuery and call the function http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TkwWE/2/. But as dystroy said, IDs **must** be unique!

Comment: "**once you include jQuery**"
Yeah, that was the problem, it seems. heh. I can't believe I didn't see that :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change

```
<div class=".main">
   <div id="#box">1</div>
   <div id="#box">2</div>
   <div id="#box">3</div>
   <div id="#box">4</div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="main">
   <div >1</div>
   <div >2</div>
   <div >3</div>
   <div >4</div>
</div>
```

Two errors :

- the `".main"` which should be "main" as you look for `$(".main").children()`.
- the id `"#box"` that you were using for more than one element

In your fiddle, you also forgot to import jQuery.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/izaxoh/1/edit) (click "Run with JS")

Comment: Well, I hadn't seen the fiddle (was it added after ?) so I fixed the code in the question (and made a fiddle to test it).

Comment: Nope, the fiddle was always there. Guess you're just getting old :P

Comment: You seem to be just as old as the old grumpy programmer I have. Is it why you're accustomed to those memory losses too ? :)

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time I did something like that I wouldn't need to work any more.

Answer (score 1):

First, as was said before, ID should be unique, and they don't start with a #. The selector for ids uses a #.

Same for classes, they should start with a letter, only the selector uses a dot.

Now for your fiddle. You visibly use jQuery, here, so include jQuery on your fiddle, in the menu on the left.

Then, what you are doing in your fiddle is defining a function, but you never call it.
Just add a call to your function at the end of your code (that will be called by jsFiddle on load of the document, like this:

`reorder();`

Worked for me on your fiddle.